# The futex facility returned an unexpected error code. Не понятны причины возникновения ошибки

Tags: c, pthread

Пишу программу на `C` с использованием `<pthread.h>`.

`pthreadobjects` - структура передаваемая нити.

```
int main{
    ...
    Pthreadobjects = (pthreadobject *)malloc(allthreads * sizeof(pthreadobject));
    pthread_barrier_init(&globalblock, NULL, allthreads + 1); //инициализировали
    //экземпляр барьера
    Pthreadobjects[i].globalblock = &globalblock; // передали структуре указатель
    pthread_create(Pthreads + i, NULL, &pthreadfunc, Pthreadobjects + i);
    pthread_barrier_wait(&globalblock); //ждём выполнения нитей
    ...
}

void * pthreadfunc(void * elem){ //функция для нити
    pthreadobject * PTHO = elem;
    pthread_barrier_wait(PTHO -> globalblock);
    return 0;
}
```

При запуске программа выдаёт некий ответ, заканчивает вычисления, но иногда возникает следующая ошибка:

> The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Кажется я тут просто забыл поджонить нити. Из-за того что они успевали доработать и без этого, программа, как правило, не падала